# Why IpcRender in electron didnt get any value from BrowserWindow.send() after build into .exe file

Tags: javascript, npm, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

i have problem that i dont know what exactly is the cause the problem is, i have simple code in `index.js` as main and `index.html`, in `main.js` the script will send the version of electron to renderer file `index.html`, when i'm try it before build that script into `.exe`, the `ipcRenderer` can get value from sended value, the following image while i run before build into `.exe` file like this :

[image that run before build into .exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COyb6.png)

but when i build it into exe file using `electron-packager .`

it didn't return any value on it after `index.js` send version in html file, the following image while the following image while i run after build into `.exe` file like this

[image that run after build into .exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIWqh.png)

This is my following script and package.json :

```
index.js

const { app, BrowserWindow,ipcMain } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule : false
    }
  })
  const appVersion = process.env.npm_package_version
  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.toggleDevTools()
  win.loadFile('index.html')
  win.webContents.on('dom-ready', () => {
      console.log(`Trying to send app version to renderer: ${appVersion}`)
      win.send('app-version', appVersion)
      console.log(`Current directory: ${process.cwd()}`);
    })
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
```

```
index.html

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="appVersion">
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    'use strict' 
    const { ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
    ipcRenderer.on('app-version', function (event,store) {
        console.log(store);
    });
</script>
```

```
package.json

{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron ."
  }, 
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^9.2.0",
    "electron-packager": "^15.0.0"
  }
}
```